# Email validation - white spaces

Tags: c#

I have the following if statement to validate email address

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(registerViewModel.Email) && !this.login.ValidateEmail(registerViewModel.Email))
{
   this.login.AddErrors(this.login.IdentityErrors.ValidEmailRequired());
}
```

this code is detecting if text box for email is empty and if email is in correct format, although is there any way to detect whitespace at the beggining and at the end of the provided email address inside if statement rather than modifying ValidateEmail method?

Comment: If you want to remove the spaces before and after the string… `emailString = emailString.Trim()` may work.

Comment: the string.Trim method is what you are looking for I believe

Comment: just fyi currently, if a user enters an empty string into your form, you won't add an error.
Since string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() will return true and you have '!' in front it, negating that true, making it false , which will make your && shortcut to false and you wont enter your code in the braces

Comment: I think your if condition is just wrong. As mentioned by Dave, you'll only add an error if the email is non-whitespace and an invalid email. Null, empty or whitespace email will return `false` for `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace` and therefore not go in the if. I won't submit this as answer since you're asking about start and end only.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Trim()` to remove whitespaces at the stand and end of string

like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(registerViewModel.Email.Trim()) && !this.login.ValidateEmail(registerViewModel.Email.Trim()))
{
   this.login.AddErrors(this.login.IdentityErrors.ValidEmailRequired());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, instead of removing spaces is there any way to detect white space before and after with string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(registerViewModel.Email)